# Average values from multiple data frames by position

Tags: r, dataframe, math

I have two dataframes:

```
dataA <- data.frame(A = replicate(5, 1), B = replicate(5, 2))
dataB <- data.frame(A = replicate(5, 3), B = replicate(5, 4))
```

I would like to create a third data frame `dataC` that is the average of the other two. For example, row 1 column 1 in the third data frame would be the average of the same position in the first two data frames.

Desired output:

```
dataC <- data.frame(A = replicate(5, 2), B = replicate(5, 3))
```

```
dataC
A   B
2   3           
2   3           
2   3           
2   3           
2   3
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use place the datasets in a `list`, do elementwise sum with `+` and divide by the lenght of the list

```
Reduce(`+`, list(dataA, dataB))/2
```

-output

```
  A B
1 2 3
2 2 3
3 2 3
4 2 3
5 2 3
```

---

Or another option is to bind the datasets while creating a grouping column based on sequence and then do the group by `mean`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
bind_rows(dataA, dataB, .id = 'grp') %>%
    group_by(grp = rowid(grp)) %>% 
    summarise(across(everything(), mean))  %>% 
    select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
      A     B
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     2     3
2     2     3
3     2     3
4     2     3
5     2     3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some solutions:

```
# method 1:
dataC <- (dataA + dataB) / 2

# method 2:
dataC <- dataA
dataC[] <- Map(function(x,y) (x+y)/2, dataA, dataB)

#   A B
# 1 2 3
# 2 2 3
# 3 2 3
# 4 2 3
# 5 2 3
```